# Goland Mac "cmd + [" and "cmd + ]" equivalent in Goland Linux

Tags: goland

Recently switch to linux for development. As title, I cannot find a Goland Mac "cmd + [" and "cmd + ]" equivalent in linux version. I tried to use ctrl instead, but seems not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean navigation to the prev/next caret position. In this case, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> on Window/Linux. You can find more information about possible ways of navigation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/navigating-through-the-source-code.html?keymap=primary_default#find_cursor_edit).